# Why is there no implicit control dependency when requesting the value of a variable with `sess.run`?

Tags: tensorflow

I want to understand if there is a reason for the following behavior which can be reproduced with the code snippet below.

When I request `sess.run` to return the value of a `Variable`, the value it returns does not depend on all operations that might update the variable being performed before returning it.

In the example here I'm testing the dependencies applied to copying the value of variable `a` into `b` before re-assigning `a` with a random value.

The process works, but the results of the first print statement are arbitrary (depending on arbitrary processing order), the results of the 2nd print statement are correct.

I would naturally expect that the value returned for tensors `a` and `b` are the variable's values at the **END** of all computations, but this is not the case.

Is there a good reason for **NOT** including an implicit control dependency on variables that are requested as part of `sess.run`?

```
import tensorflow as tf

a = tf.Variable(0.0)
b = tf.Variable(0.0)
r = tf.random_normal(shape=())

op_a2b = tf.assign(b, a)

with tf.control_dependencies([op_a2b]):
  op_r2a = tf.assign(a, r)

sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

print(sess.run([a, b, r, op_r2a, op_a2b]))
print(sess.run([a, b]))
```

Results below. Notice that the values of `a`, and `b` are different between calls to `sess.run` though they don't change. This demonstrates that tensorflow doesn't guarantee the return value of a Variable be the last thing computed before return.

```
[0.0, 0.0, 0.79926836, 0.79926836, 0.0]
[0.79926836, 0.0]
```

Comment: I ran your example with v1.11 and in the result I got, the first output number was non-zero, unlike for you. I suspect `Session.run()` can arbitrarily give you the value of the variable from before or after assignments. More freedom and fewer constraints means more opportunities for optimizing the computation. `tf.assign()` gives you the value from after the assignment but I don't know what will give you the value from before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there's two things to explain.

Remember that TensorFlow builds a computational graph and then `sess` runs it. Think of it like this: You're defining a loop body and then `sess` iterates through it once per call. In that context, you wouldn't expect `a` to return the result of `op_r2a` - since `a` is like an initial condition and `op_r2a` is like an update in the loop body. I think that addresses your question as to the good reason why there is not an implicit control dependency.

But, you can force it with `tf.control_dependencies` *inside a block of code* (which is why `sess` is still going to return the "pre-assignment" value). It's useful when defining batch norm, for example. However, your `with tf.control_dependencies` isn't doing anything. You assign `b <- a` outside of the `with` block, and you assign `a <- r` after. What's inside the `with` block doesn't depend on what's outside.

I updated your code to try to explain this.

```
import tensorflow as tf

# Define a graph, a_t <- r_{t-1}; b_t <- a_t
a = tf.Variable(0.0)
b = tf.Variable(1.0)
r = tf.random_normal(shape=())

update_a = tf.assign(a, r)
with tf.control_dependencies([update_a]):
    # JUST to illustrate tf.control_dependencies, 
    # make `a` take the value of `update_a`.
    update_b = tf.assign(b, a)
update_b_differently = tf.assign(b, update_a)

sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

# Run it
print("Timestep 1:")
a0, b0, r1, a1, b1, bx = sess.run([a, b, r, update_a, update_b, 
                                  update_b_differently])
print("a_0 =", a0, "--> a_1 =", a1, "(= r_1 =", r1, ")")
print("b_0 =", b0, "--> b_1 =", b1, "(= a_1 =", a1, ")")
print("update_b =", b1, "= update_b_differently =", bx)

print("\nTimestep 2 (Don't step up, just check initial conditions)")
a1_again, b1_again = sess.run([a, b])
print("a_1 =", a1_again, "is the initial condition for T.S. 2")
print("b_1 =", b1_again, "is the initial condition for T.S. 2")
```

which outputs

```
Timestep 1:
a_0 = 0.0 --> a_1 = 0.0190619 (= r_1 = 0.0190619 )
b_0 = 1.0 --> b_1 = 0.0190619 (= a_1 = 0.0190619 )
update_b = 0.0190619 = update_b_differently = 0.0190619

Timestep 2 (Don't step up, just check initial conditions)
a_1 = 0.0190619 is the initial condition for T.S. 2
b_1 = 0.0190619 is the initial condition for T.S. 2
```

Notice we assigned to `tf.Variable(0.0)` and used a `tf.control_dependencies` to make it persistent when assigning to `update_b`, but `sess.run(a)` still returns 0. But, the new value of `a` stays with `update_b` when `update_b` exits the `with` block. That is, `update_b` is dependent on `update_a` changing the value of `a`, but the value of the `tf.Variable(0.0)` remains unchanged until the next call to `sess.run`.